# Diagonal split a video in one side visibile and other invisible

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my website I have two video but I want to watch both, by splitting the screen in a diagonal way. In one side we will have our first video in the other side, the second.

Is it possibile to create something similar in javascript or css3?

I'm trying in this way but the image is rotating? other solution

**CSS**

```
    .set {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    section {
        position: absolute;
        top: -100%;
        height: 500vw;
        width: 500vh;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
    section + section {
        background: #666;
        top: 0%;
    }
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="set">
    <section id="a_hov">
        <a href="">
            <img src="example1" alt="" />
        </a>
    </section>

    <section id="b_hov">
        <a href="">
            <img src="example2" alt="" />
        </a>
    </section>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
        $(function() {
             $(window).on('resize', function() {
                     var h = $(document).height(),
                             w = $(document).width();

                    /*  Math.atan() function returns the arctangent (in radians)
                     *  of a number and 1 rad ~= 57.29577 deg
                     */
                     var angle = Math.atan(h/w) * 57.29577;
                     var rotateProperty = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";

                     $('section').css({
                            "-webkit-transform": rotateProperty,
                            "-moz-transform": rotateProperty,
                            "transform": rotateProperty
                     });

             })
             .triggerHandler('resize');
        });
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J8l1.png)

Comment: "*Is it possible...?*" - yes. What's your relevant ("*[mcve]*") HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Comment: I past my code but I think is far away from solution :/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with CSS `clip-path` property.

Useful site for generating it: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

**Note: IE and Edge have no support for this property** (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

```js
document.getElementById("play1").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var v = document.getElementById("vid1").play();
});
    
document.getElementById("play2").addEventListener("click",function(){
  document.getElementById("vid2").play();
});
    
document.getElementById("playBoth").addEventListener("click",function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].play();  
  document.getElementsByTagName("video")[1].play();
});
```

```css
#vid1{
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 100%);
}
#vid2{
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="vid1"></video><!--
--><video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="vid2"></video>

<button id="play1">Play Vid1</button>
<button id="play2">Play Vid2</button>
<button id="playBoth">Play Both</button>
```

Comment: Nice demo @yuriy636 , clip-path is not that well supported though, the user should be aware of this. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: @RicardoRuiz True, was going to add that to the answer.